# Gebrauchsanweisung für Gräzismen und Latinismen

Tags: latin

Ich war kurz davor, eine Frage zu einem Gräzismus zu stellen, aber langfristig wäre wohl Folgendes hilfreicher:

Gibt es eine gute Referenz, wie Gräzismen (und Latinismen) in der deutschen Standardsprache verwendet werden, mit besonderem Augenmerk auf:

1. Schriftliche Eindeutschung ("Gräzismus" ist ein Beispiel)
2. Herkunft, Bedeutung, und korrekte Verwendung der Wortendungen (-ik,-istisch,-ie, usw.)

Comment: Wenn ich es richtig in Erinnerung habe, gab es mehrere Fragen zum Gebrauch verschiedener spezifischer Latinismen. Die Antworten auf die Fragen waren jeweils sehr allgemein. Ggf. Findest du etwas hilfreiches bei tiefergehender Suche

Comment: Teil 2 deiner Frage ist mir unklar. Mußt du mal erläutern. Teil 1 sollte im Fremdwörterbuch beantwortet werden. Oder halt direkt aus der Ursprungssprache. Zum Beispiel finde ich »Graecismus« auch völlig in Ordnung, weil es eben so auf Latein heißt. Oder was meinst du sonst? Ich glaub, deiner Frage fehlen die Beispiele; die mußt du bringen, damit sie konkret wird.

Answer (score 1):

Die Wikipedia hat eine sehr schoene Liste, eventuell hilft die dir weiter. 
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Gr%C3%A4zismen

Comment: Bitte antworte nicht nur mit einem Link, sondern erkläre warum die verlinkte Seite die Frage beantwortet. Außerdem tut sie Letzteres nur mit starken Einschränkungen, da sie nur Gräzismen listet, aber keine Systematik für ihre Schreibung angibt (sondern nur ein paar Beispiele auflistet, die unsystematisch sind, also von einer möglichen Systematik abweichen).

Comment: ok, ich gebe zu der erste punkt wird wirklich nur tangiert. Aber Teil 2 der Frage wird in jedem sub-Artikel geklärt

Comment: Hmm, zumindest in ein paar Stichproben nicht. So oder so, genau das solltest Du ausführen …

Comment: Please do not add link-only answers. We should at least quote the content with appropriate reference to the source.

Comment: the problem is, he ask for an reference so there is one. it would be fine when shuhalo could say if this list fits or not. If this is not something he ask for we can delete my post :)

Comment: Stack Exchange Seiten sind in aller Regel nicht für solche Fragen geeignet (*list questions*). Wir machen hier aber manchmal eine Ausnahme. Eine Antwort sollte aber immer mehr sein als nur ein Link zu einer Seite. Erkläre z.B., warum du meinst, dass der Artikel die Frage gut beantwortet, welche Fragen unbeantwortet bleiben und gib evtl. noch ein Beispiel, wie die Liste aufgebaut ist.

Comment: @Takkat: So, wie ich das verstanden habe, richtet sich die Frage doch gar nicht nach einer Liste aller Gräzismen, sondern nach allegemeinen Aspekten, z. B. dem Transkriptionsschema und der Bedeutung gewisser Endungen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft auch eine Liste von Referenzen ist problematisch, da vermutlich klein kann man die Frage aber gelten lassen.